# ¿Como aplicar busquea binaria con String al leer un txt?

Tags: c#

Buenas amigos, verán de tengo que realizar la lectura de un archivo txt con datos "nombre","teléfono" y posteriormente realizar la búsqueda binaria de algún nombre en el.

Ya realicé la lectura del archivo txt y separé los datos que hay en el mediante comas, sin embargo no entiendo como puedo enviar el arreglo con los valores separados al método que realizará la busqueda.

> Esto es lo que tengo en mi clase principal

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace busquedaAgenda
{
    class Agenda
    {
        //Arreglo que tendrá los datos separados
        public static ArrayList Registro = new ArrayList();

        //Método para separar los datos del archivo
        public void leer(String nomBusca)
        {
            string linea;       //Cada linea de texto
            String[] separar;   //Arreglo que tendrá por separados los datos
            Contacto cont = new Contacto(); //objeto que servirá para ir guardando los registros

            StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("Contactos.txt");
            while ((linea = archivo.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Separar mediante comas
                separar = linea.Split(',');

                //Se establece el orden y los datos que se guardaran
                cont.Nombre = separar[0];
                cont.Telefono = separar[1];

                //Se guarda en el registro
                Registro.Add(cont);


            }
            archivo.Close();

            //Llamar método que realizará la busqueda binaria
            Contacto.busquedaBinaria(Registro, nomBusca);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Agenda nuevo = new Agenda();
            String nombre;

            Console.WriteLine("\tAgenda telefónica\n");

            //solicuta nombre a buscar
            Console.Write("\nContacto a buscar: ");
            nombre = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            //Enviar el nombre al método que leerá los datos
            nuevo.leer(nombre);

            //Contacto.busquedaBinaria(Registro, nombre);

        }
    }
}
```

> Esta es mi otra clase que tiene el método para realizar la búsqueda binaria

```
using System.Collections;
using System;

namespace busquedaAgenda
{
    class Contacto
    {
        //Propiedades autoimplementadas
        public String Nombre { get; set; }
        public String Telefono { get; set; }

        public Contacto()
        {
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
            this.Telefono = Telefono;
        }

        public static void busquedaBinaria(ArrayList datos, string nomBuscar)
        {
            int izq, der, centro;
            izq = 0;
            der = datos.Count - 1;
            centro = (izq + der) / 2;

            Console.WriteLine(datos[centro]);
            while (nomBuscar != datos[centro] && izq < der)
            {
                if (nomBuscar > datos[centro])
                {
                    izq = centro + 1;
                }
                if (nomBuscar < datos[centro])
                {
                    der = centro - 1;
                }
                centro = (izq + der) / 2;
            }
            if (nomBuscar == datos[centro])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"El número {nomBuscar} se encuentra en la posición {centro}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"El número {nomBuscar} no se encuentra");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Si alguien fuera amable de decirme como poder mandar el los datos del Registro o una mejor forma de separar los datos, se lo agradecería.

Comment: `izq < der` siempre será `true`, de acuerdo al valor de `izq` y si el valor de `der` es mayor que 0, la comparación `nomBuscar > datos[centro]` no es correcta, no puedes evaluar `string` con `object` o `Contacto`, y nunca sacas los datos del arraylist... Por lo que no saldrá del ciclo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar System.Collections.Generic;
Debes tener cuidado cuando usas una lista en un ciclo, por cada elemento que agregas debes crear una instancia.
Para comparar string puedes usar el método CompareTo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Agenda
{
    //Arreglo que tendrá los datos separados
    List<Contacto> Registro = new List<Contacto>();

    //Método para separar los datos del archivo
    public void leer(String nomBusca)
    {
        string linea;       //Cada linea de texto
        String[] separar;   //Arreglo que tendrá por separados los datos

        StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("Contactos.txt");
        while ((linea = archivo.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Contacto cont = new Contacto();
            //Separar mediante comas
            separar = linea.Split(',');

            //Se establece el orden y los datos que se guardaran
            cont.Nombre = separar[0];
            cont.Telefono = separar[1];

            //Se guarda en el registro
            Registro.Add(cont);


        }
        archivo.Close();

        //Llamar método que realizará la busqueda binaria
        Contacto.busquedaBinaria(Registro, nomBusca);
    }

    class Contacto
    {
        //Propiedades autoimplementadas
        public String Nombre { get; set; }
        public String Telefono { get; set; }

        public Contacto()
        {
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
            this.Telefono = Telefono;
        }

        public static void busquedaBinaria(List<Contacto> datos, string nomBuscar)
        {
            int izq, der, centro;
            izq = 0;
            der = datos.Count - 1;
            centro = (izq + der) / 2;

            Console.WriteLine(datos[centro].Nombre);
            while (nomBuscar != datos[centro].Nombre && izq < der)
            {
                int comparacion = nomBuscar.CompareTo(datos[centro].Nombre);

                if (comparacion > 0)
                {
                    izq = centro + 1;
                }
                if (comparacion < 0)
                {
                    der = centro - 1;
                }
                centro = (izq + der) / 2;
            }
            if (nomBuscar == datos[centro].Nombre)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El número {0} se encuentra en la posición {1}", nomBuscar, centro);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El número {0} no se encuentra", nomBuscar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de hecho tienes razón con el manejo de la lista en lugar del array, me fue más sencillo el manejar los datos y poder hacer las modificaciones necesarias. Ten un excelente día

Answer (score 0):

Si tambien el problema como lo demuestra la respuesta anterior
es que estabas comparando un objeto `datos[centro]` contra un string:

> error--->while (nomBuscar != datos[centro] && izq < der)

Aquí debajo se compara el nombre del objeto contra el nombre buscado.

> okey---> while (nomBuscar != datos[centro].Nombre && izq < der)